# Adding indices to a BufferGeometry does not work?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have been trying to draw a very basic rectangle using THREE.BufferGeometry(). Here is the code -

```
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'});


var verticesArray = [20, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, -20, 0, 0, 0, -20, 0];
var vertices = new Float32Array(verticesArray, 0, 12);

var indicesArray = [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3];
var indices = new Uint16Array(indicesArray, 0, 6);

geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
//geometry.addAttribute('index', new THREE.BufferAttribute(indices, 3));
geometry.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(indices, 3));


var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

Unfortunately it isn't working. It isn't throwing any exception either. To my understanding, i have done everything right. I have four vertices, and i have described two set of indices in counter clockwise order.

Could anyone please tell me what can go wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be `geometry.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(indices, 1));`